# Visual Studio 2010 C++ native debug mode resources

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, native

I am very desperate now...

I have project in Visual C++ 2010 using Qt and OpenCV. I got to phase I need to load XML file using openCV. But, I have no idea where is the working directory of my project, when run thru VS (F5). I mean, I read all config, copied desired file almost everywhere in my project folders, but it still is not seen by my EXE (OpenCV)...

What Am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on your project click on properties/Configuration Properties/debugging you start in whatever working directory is set to.

Comment: Hmm there must be some other problem than... I have desired file in this directory already...

Comment: do an outputdebugstring with the value returned from getcurrentdirectory

Comment: Well, appearently working dir is where it should be... I guess some problem with OpenCV then. Thanks :)